# "in the plate" or "on the plate"

Tags: prepositions

I am learning English with Duolingo.

One example sentence is:

> The forks are **on the plates.**

Another one is:

> I have her fork **in my plate.**

What's the difference between "in the plate" and "on the plate"?

Comment: I don't think I've never heard "in the plate". The fork goes _on_ the plate, and the spoon goes _in_ the bowl.

Comment: It should be noted that the latter example has been reported (and accepted) as wrong on [this comment thread](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/1457433) and noted to be incorrect (in Russian) [here](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/1514031).

Comment: Update to my previous remark: after further research, I was able to find a few scant instances where "in" was used instead of "on." _Grandma put some boiled potatoes in my plate and I thanked her_ (Hannah Roslin, 2010). It still sounds decidedly unusual to me, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *literal* sense is...

> [**plate**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plate) *- a shallow, usually circular dish, often of earthenware or porcelain, from which food is eaten.*

It's not always possible to classify any given item as a *plate* or a *bowl*, but the general principle is that plates are ***flat*** surfaces, so food (or anything else) goes ***on*** them. In contrast, bowls are (also usually circular) ***containers*** with raised sides - capable of holding liquids such as soup, which goes ***in*** them.

Thus OP's example usage #1 is what we would normally expect when describing the spatial relationship between the forks and the plates.

---

But note the figurative sense #2 in my link - *the **contents** of such a dish; **plateful,*** and consider [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20my%20plate%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22her%20fork%20in%20his%20plate%22&tbm=bks)

> *"Someday, I hope you'll mean that," she replied, sticking her fork **in his plate** for a quick taste.*

As a native speaker, my natural inclination is to interpret OP's second example in terms of that second definition (she sticks her fork *into the food* on his plate, in order to help herself to some of it).

---

TL;DR: Things are usually located ***on*** plates (including the figurative *"I had too much **on my plate** already to take on another task"* as per the idiomatic sense 34 in my link above). Usages such as [*"Lindsey stopped eating and set her fork **in her plate.**"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20my%20plate%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22set%20her%20fork%20in%20her%20plate%22&tbm=bks) are relatively uncommon, so native speakers may well look for an alternative interpretation to explain/justify the unusual preposition.

Comment: I'm removing my answer and voting this one up.  As an aside, on chat Damkerng found "in a [covered cake plate](http://www.retroplanet.com/mm5/graphics/prods/23517-sp.jpg)": a plate with a cover, I suppose, is conceptualized as having an interior.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was trying to explain, only more clearly explained. I, too, am removing my answer and upvoting yours.

Comment: I slipped a number of "hedges" in there *(usually, normally, often, tend, may, etc.)*. Comparing Google Books results for [*"{stubbed out a} cigarette **in** his plate"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cigarette+in+his+plate%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) shows the ***on*** version is about ten times more common. In most contexts it's not that the "non-standard" version is "wrong". It's just not very common.

Comment: As another native speaker - my interpretation of "in the plate" makes me picture a spoon that has melded with and become *embedded within* the plate.

Comment: Yeah, discussions of things "in the plate" had better be a discussion of, say, inclusions or faults in the ceramic, e.g. "We discovered after opening the kiln post-firing that an air pocket in the plate had ruptured, destroying it and three mugs besides."

Comment: Plates come from a French word meaning "flat". (But in French, you also have  plates,slightly deep for soups).

Answer (score 1):

I think that, over the past few years at least, plates have become less flat, that is, with more elevated sides.  Maybe because of the variety of cuisines--more liquids for example--a deeper plate has been desirable. The top outside edge of our white plates at home is 1" above the bottom edge, for example.  That's not flat, not like our heavy brown dishes.  That's enough for me to start to think of food as being *in* the white plates but still *on* the brown ones.  So the more that plates resemble bowls, the more likely it is that English speakers will instinctively start to say, "in the plate" instead of "on the plate," etc.

Answer (score 0):

If a plate is has higher sides to it then it is a shallow bowl not a plate.
 As a Native English Speaker O have always said on the plate and in the bowl.
Agreed that  if a person said  they put  their fork in his plate  it would assume that it was into his food ..
If you said the fork was on the plate you would assume some sort of art work whereby the fork was embedded in the plate